# How to connect a light dimmer for my lamp

Tags: light, dimming

I have a light dimmer i want to connect to a a floor lamp. I have tried to look for some diagrams but haven't been able to find some.

There is a diagram on the dimmer but I don't understand it.

I have made an illustration to show how the small diagram looks (it's the diagram in the middle, the lamp and the 4 wires and the power plug are my additions.

http://000fff.org/uploads/LightDimmer.pdf

Can anyone tell me how to connect this. I have 1 wire from the lamp to the dimmer with a blue and a brown wire and 1 wire from the dimmer to the power with a blue and a brown wire.

Comment: You should really have a licensed electrician do this for you, inexperience working with mains voltage wiring can possibly kill.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I am not working with it plugged in though (only to check). And the setup is fairly safe (the light dimmer sits in a box). I have fixed plenty of wires before this is just new to me.

Comment: I solved it thanks for your help I found an actual illustration. It turns out I should only use 3 of the slots, the fourth (the one with the circle and the lines) was for earthquake. And I needed to take the two neutral wires and put them in the same slot (N)

Comment: It seems that your question got cut off at the bottom. Could you fix the missing info? I may then be able to improve my answer.

Comment: Could you post the illustration, then post an answer with what you did? After you post your answer, accept it. This way, others will be able to learn from your experiences.

Comment: "the fourth (the one with the circle and the lines) was for earthquake." -- actually, it would be "earth", or as we say in the US, ground, which would be used if you had a three terminal plug instead of two.

Comment: You are right of course. Earth not earthquake :)

Comment: This seems like a very good question for the home improvement SE. http://diy.stackexchange.com/ is pretty much dedicated to working on houses, setting up wiring and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your illustration, it seems that the mains wires are the two left wires, and the lamp would connect to the two right wires. You mentioned that the dimmer is in an enclosure. I would strongly recommend ensuring that there is absolutely no way that a determined toddler could get a screwdriver, paperclip, ham sandwich, etc... into the enclosure. Also ensure that the wires are protected with some sort of strain relief, so that when the dog trips on the cord, the wires won't come out.

---

### EDIT:

I looked at your drawing again. It seems that there are two possibilities:

***First Possibility***

You are seeing 4 wires because they are 2 from the cord, and 2 from the socket. This one's easy. Connect the two wires from the plug to the left two wire positions on the dimmer. Connect the other two wires to the right two wire positions on the dimmer.

***Second Possibility***

Your lamp socket is wired for a three-way lamp. Usually these have 3 wires, though. One would be the neutral, one would be low, and one would be medium. With power applied to both low and medium, you get high power. You would need to check this with an ohmmeter. With a 3-way bulb installed, measure resistances across all of the wires. You should come up with something like this:

```
Pair    Measurement
1-2 360
1-3 240
1-4 0
2-3 600
2-4 360
3-4 240
```

Note that these numbers are approximate, and depend on the wattage of your bulb. This table is built on the assumption of a 40-60-100 Watt bulb. In this case, 1 and 4 are Neutral and Ground, and can be tied together. 2 is low power, and 3 is medium power. Using an external dimmer, these should also tie together for the hot side. Check across the neutral/ground and 
the hot side. If it reads short, there's a problem!

## ***CAUTION***

If you can't figure out exactly what each wire is for, get help! Magic smoke stinks, and so do house fires. (Been there. Not cool.)

As tronixstuff mentioned before, though, mains can kill. I've been "tagged" a few times (lucky -- I'm still here to write about it) and you need to exercise the utmost caution.

Comment: That is what I have done so far. The lamp in the right and the power in the left doesn't seem to work. I have also tried to switch around the blue and brown wires. Someone told me that I might not need to use all 4 wires (two on the cable from the lamp and two on the cable to the power plug) don't know if that is correct? With regards to safety I have a one year old so I am very cautious.

Comment: I can also add the dimmer box is called Rondo from from Relco i tried to look it up but haven't been able to find the brand anywhere

Comment: This is the correct way to solve it and you are right it's second possibility (3 way lamp)

000fff.org/uploads/82200800_RONDO.pdf